# Python Splinter click isnt working

Tags: python, splinter

I just started working with python + splinter

http://splinter.cobrateam.info/docs/tutorial.html

Unfortunately I can't get the example to work.

I cannot tell if:

```
 browser.find_by_name('btnG')
```

is finding anything.

Second, I try to click the button with
    button = browser.find_by_name('btnG').first
    button.click()

This does not throw an error but NOTHING HAPPENS.

I tried again with the tutorial:
http://f.souza.cc/2011/05/splinter-python-tool-for-acceptance.html

and I got stuck again with the CLICK.

I am using python 2.7.3, and the latest stuff from splinter/selenium today.

How can I troublehsoot this problem (is anyone else having a problem)?

Answer (score 1):

When all else fails update firefox.

I upgraded my Jan 9, 2014 version and things could click!

Answer (score 0):

The name of the button in my (Chromium) browser as of now is `'btnK'`.